# jQuery append list items with each loop fails to append to correct place

Tags: jquery, html-lists, each

I'm trying to append ul to existing list items with each loop but its fails to place at correct position that i want. here is the jsfiddle link [wrong result](http://jsfiddle.net/yzp5L/19/).
this is what i want to achieve [correct result](http://jsfiddle.net/kml5ive/jj5AG/)

this is my html

```
<ul class="rows">
 <li>row</li>
 <li>row</li>
 <li>row</li>
 <li>row</li>
 <li>row</li>
</ul>
<ul class="ins">
    <li>columns</li>
    <li>columns</li>
</ul>
<ul class="ins">
    <li>columns</li>
    <li>columns</li>
</ul>
<ul class="ins">
    <li>columns</li>
    <li>columns</li>
</ul>

<ul class="ins">
    <li>columns</li>
    <li>columns</li>
</ul>
<ul class="ins">
    <li>columns</li>
    <li>columns</li>
</ul>
```

a want to achieve this structure by using jQuery append

```
<ul class="rows">
    <li>
        row
        <ul class="ins">
            <li>columns</li>
            <li>columns</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        row
        <ul class="ins">
            <li>columns</li>
            <li>columns</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        row
        <ul class="ins">
            <li>columns</li>
            <li>columns</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        row
        <ul class="ins">
            <li>columns</li>
            <li>columns</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        row
        <ul class="ins">
            <li>columns</li>
            <li>columns</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        row
        <ul class="ins">
            <li>columns</li>
            <li>columns</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
​
```

Comment: What do you mean by row? What kind of element?

Comment: ignore the text 'row' its just a placeholder please check the jsfiddle links, i want each of the 'ins' un-ordered lists append to 'rows' list items by respected order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$('.ins').each(function(index,e){
    $('.ins').eq(index).appendTo($('.rows').children().eq(index));
});
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: no problem.  You were very close.
Remember that for this to work properly you need to have the same amount of '.ins' as '.rows <li>'